# Creation of symlinks

Tags: directory, symlink

I am following the tutorial http://www.olindata.com/blog/2013/12/building-ha-cluster-openvz-drbd-heartbeat-and-pacemaker. I got up to here:

```
symlink folders in /var/lib/vz to /etc/vz
```

The `/etc/vz` has two folders: `names` and `dists`. At the previous step I moved these two folders on `/var/lib/vz`.

Now, in order to create the symlinks I did the following:

```
[root@primary vz]# cd dists
[root@primary dists]# ln -s /etc/vz symlink1

[root@primary vz]# cd names
[root@primary names]# ln -s /etc/vz/names symlink2
```

In order to verify, I used `ls -la` command.

```
[root@primary vz]# cd names
[root@primary names]# ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   13 Jun 10 10:58 symlink2 -> /etc/vz/names

[root@primary vz]# cd dists
[root@primary dists]# ls -la
rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   13 Jun 10 10:58 symlink1 -> /etc/vz/dists
```

Now, I'm not really sure if I did `symlink folders in /var/lib/vz to /etc/vz` or I misunterstood the requirement and i should've done it differently.

Comment: What do you mean by `symlink folders in /var/lib/vz to /etc/vz` . You just created two symlinks pointing to `/etc/vz/names` and `/etc/vz/dists`. What's your requirement?

Comment: By requirement I mean `symlink folders in /var/lib/vz to /etc/vz`. And because I'm not sure how should I interpret that sentence I chose to make this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were told to "symlink folders in /var/lib/vz **to /etc/vz**". This means you need to create a link in `/etc/vz` pointing to each of the directories in `/var/lib/vz`. To do that, run:

```
ln -s /var/lib/vz/names /etc/vz
ln -s /var/lib/vz/dists /etc/vz
```

That will create the symlinks `/etc/vz/names` and `/etc/vz/dists` which point to `/var/lib/vz/names` and `/var/lib/vz/dists` respectively.

Comment: You mean the way I did it I created symlinks `/var/lib/vz/names` and `/var/lib/vz/dists` which point to `/etc/vz/names` and `/etc/vz/dists` repectively?

Comment: @TanatosDaniel I'm not sure what you did since that will depend on which directory you ran the command from. You created a link called `symlink1` in `vz/dists` (I don't know if that was `/etc/vz` or `/lib.vz`) which pointed to `/etc/vz` and one called `symlink2` in `vz/names` which pointed to `/etc/vz/names`.

Comment: Oh. You're right. The folders have the same names. The commands were run from `/var/lib/vz/dists` and `/var/lib/vz/names`

Comment: @TanatosDaniel OK, in that case, you created the following symlinks: `/var/lib/vz/dists/symlink1 -> /etc/vz` and `/var/lib/vz/names/symlink2 -> /etc/vz/names`. Just remove the two symlinks and run the command from my answer to create the right ones.

Comment: Ok. So I have created them backwards. I get it now. Thanks!